# how to insert into a single column of mysql I have two JCheckBox using java?

Tags: java, insert, resultset

**one JCheckBoxwill be insert into the database**

```
String R=chckbxRsidentel.getSelectedObjects().toString();
String A=chckbxAffaire.getSelectedObjects().toString();
```

Comment: I want to insert either "R" or "A" into the database depending on which checkbox is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want to insert either "R" or "A" into the database depending on which checkbox is selected. Perhaps you also want to insert, say, " " if neither is selected.

You could do this:

```
char check = chckbxRsidentel.isSelected() ? "R" :
             chckbxAffaire.isSelected() ? "A" : " ";
```

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to char

Comment: Fixed the string / char mismatch

Comment: and in the request what I write for the variable

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near